# The fe(JS)&be(Python) coupling of RSA encryption

Tags: javascript, python, rsa, pycryptodome, jsencrypt

I am using `RSA` algorithm to encrypt data. The frontend uses the `window.crypto` and the backend uses the `pycryptodome`.

However, I discovered that after the frontend encrypts a payload, the backend can't decrypt it. The  frontend refers `MDN`'s example code: https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/main/web-crypto/import-key/spki.js, and my code is not shown on GitHub now. The backend is copied from the example which is written by myself: https://github.com/zvms/rsa-bcrypt-jwt-login-eg/blob/main/cert.py. The full code is showed here:

### Frontend

> crpyto.ts

```js
// Function to convert PEM formatted public key to a CryptoKey object
async function importPublicKey(pemKey: string) {
  const withoutNewlines = pemKey
    .replace('-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----', '')
    .replace('-----END PUBLIC KEY-----', '')
    .split('\n')
    .filter((line) => line.trim() !== '')
    .join('')
  console.log(withoutNewlines)
  // Base64 decode the string to get the binary data
  const binaryDerString = window.atob(withoutNewlines)
  // Convert from a binary string to an ArrayBuffer
  const binaryDer = str2ab(binaryDerString)

  return window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    'spki',
    binaryDer,
    {
      name: 'RSA-OAEP',
      hash: 'SHA-256' // Specify the hash algorithm
    },
    true,
    ['encrypt']
  )
}

// Utility function to convert a binary string to an ArrayBuffer
function str2ab(str: string) {
  const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length)
  const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf)
  for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i)
  }
  return buf
}

// Function to encrypt data using RSA-OAEP
async function encryptData(publicKey: CryptoKey, data: string) {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder()
  const encodedData = encoder.encode(data)

  const encryptedData = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
    {
      name: 'RSA-OAEP'
    },
    publicKey,
    encodedData
  )

  return encryptedData
}

export { importPublicKey, encryptData }
```

> auth.ts

```js
async function UserLogin(user: string, password: string, term: 'long' | 'short' = 'long') {
  const payload = JSON.stringify({
    password: password,
    time: Date.now()
  })
  const publicKey = await importPublicKey(await getRSAPublicCert())
  const credential = await encryptData(publicKey, payload)
  // console.log(credential)
  const hex = byteArrayToHex(new Uint8Array(credential))
  console.log(`User ${user} login with ${term} term, with the credential ${hex}`)
  const result = (await axios('/user/auth', {
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      id: user.toString(),
      credential: hex,
      mode: term
    }
  })) as Response<LoginResult>
}
```

### Backend

```py
import bcrypt
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from fastapi import HTTPException
import jwt
import json
import datetime
from database import db
from bson import ObjectId
from bcrypt import checkpw


class Auth:
    password: str
    time: int


def hash_password(password):
    return bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode("utf-8"), bcrypt.gensalt())


def check_password(password, hashed):
    return bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode("utf-8"), hashed)


public_key = RSA.import_key(open("rsa_public_key.pem", "rb").read())
private_key = RSA.import_key(open("rsa_private_key.pem", "rb").read())
jwt_private_key = open("aes_key.txt", "r").read()


def rsa_encrypt(plaintext):
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(public_key)
    encrypt_text = cipher.encrypt(bytes(plaintext.encode("utf8")))
    return encrypt_text.hex()


def rsa_decrypt(ciphertext):
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
    decrypt_text = cipher.decrypt(bytes.fromhex(ciphertext))
    return decrypt_text.decode("utf8")


def jwt_encode(id: str):
    payload = {
        "exp": datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=60),
        "iat": datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
        "sub": id,
        "scope": "access_token",
        "type": "long-term",
    }
    return jwt.encode(payload, jwt_private_key, algorithm="HS256")


def jwt_decode(token):
    return jwt.decode(token, jwt_private_key, algorithms=["HS256"], verify=True)


def validate_by_cert(id: str, cert: str):
    auth_field = json.loads(rsa_decrypt(cert))
    time = auth_field["time"]
    # in a minute
    if time > datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() + 60:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Token expired")

    if checkpwd(id, auth_field["password"]):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Password incorrect")

    return jwt_encode(id)

def checkpwd(id: str, pwd: str):
    user = db.zvms.users.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)})
    if checkpw(bytes(pwd, 'utf-8'), user.get('password')):
        return True
    return False
```

and the api handler directly calls `validate_by_cert` method.

### Key Generation

Directly use `openssl`.

```bash
openssl genrsa -out rsa_private_key.pem 1024
openssl rsa -in rsa_private_key.pem -pubout -out rsa_public_key.pem
openssl rand -hex 32 > aes_key.txt
```

## Behavior

It returns `error` when calling this `api`:

```
  File "/Users/*/**/zvms/routers/users_router.py", line 43, in auth_user
    result = validate_by_cert(id, credential)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/*/**/zvms/util/cert.py", line 59, in validate_by_cert
    auth_field = json.loads(rsa_decrypt(cert))
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/*/**/zvms/util/cert.py", line 39, in rsa_decrypt
    decrypt_text = cipher.decrypt(bytes.fromhex(ciphertext))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/*/anaconda3/envs/zvms/lib/python3.12/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_OAEP.py", line 191, in decrypt
    raise ValueError("Incorrect decryption.")
```

However, when I call the native `rsa_encrypt` method and use it to decrypt, it works well.

The frontend and backend can transfer encrypted data successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The Python stack trace shows that the error is caused in `rsa_decrypt()`.

The RSA decryption fails because in the Python/PyCryptodome code the default value, namely SHA-1, is used as (OAEP and MGF1) digest, see [`Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP.new()`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/oaep.html#Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP.new), description of `hashAlgo` parameter, while in the JavaScript/WebCrypto code SHA-256 is applied (see the `window.crypto.subtle.importKey()` call).

To use SHA-256 on the Python side as well, fix in `rsa_decrypt()`:

```py
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
...
cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key, hashAlgo = SHA256)
```

With this change, decryption works for me.